# summing data in different temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 temp tables inside a procedure having data like see at the bottom of this ost.

In temporary table `table 1` I have phone tickets for each category and each department d1 and d2.

Similarly in temporary table `Table 2`  I have IVR tickets for each category and each department d1 and d2.

Now I need to sum phone and IVR tickets and show as another temp table.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

[image: Result]

Comment: *"Now I need to sum phone and IVR tickets and show as another temp table."* Great! Good luck and thanks for telling us. If you get stuck, then please do ask us a question, showing us what you've tried, and explain why it doesn't work. Include sample data (**not** images) and expected results and I'm sure someone will be more than happy to help you if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `full join` if the two table don't have the same number of rows:

```
select coalesce(t1.categoryname, t2.categoryname) as categoryname,
       coalesce(t1.departmentname, t2.departmentname) as departmentname,
       coalesce(phonetickets, 0) + coalesce(ivrtickets, 0) as total_tickets
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.categoryname = t2.categoryname and
        t1.departmentname = t2.departmentname;
```

If the two tables have the same categories and departments, then `inner join` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can USE a `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY` to get the result that you want

```
;WITH tckts as (
Select 
  CategoryName
  ,DepartmentName
  ,PhoneTickets [Tickets]
FROM Table1 t1
UNION ALL
Select 
  CategoryName
  ,DepartmentName
  ,IVRTickets [Tickets]
FROM Table2 t2
)
SELECT 
  CategoryName
  ,DepartmentName
  ,SUM(Tickets) [TotalTickets]
FROM tckts
GROUP BY CategoryName, DepartmentName
```

A better way to do the same would be to create a single table for both Phone Tickets and IVR Tickets and have a column, lets say [TicketType] which will have a value describing whether the ticket is a Phone Ticket or an IVR Ticket or any other Ticket types you have  in the Future

Comment: FYI, `;` is a statement **terminator**, not a "beginningator". It goes at the end of your statement(s), not the start.

Comment: Ahh yes, it has become a practice of mine since you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon for a CTE to work. Same with the `WITH` before `(nolock)` , is not necessary in this case but I tend to use it

Comment: `NOLOCK` is a completely different problem, and I actually am not sure why you have used it here other than to cause the results to potentionally be wrong. But the `WITH` prior *is* needed for any table hint; not using it is deprecated (as it not terminating your statements correctly).

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Considering that you don't explain the huge implications of `NOLOCK` here, this is actually a very dangerous answer.